# NameError: name 'sequences' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the Jupyter notebook:

Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

Any help?

```
NameError     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-6934f5f7b183> in <module>()
33 read_fasta(file_name)
34 print("Start2")
---> 35 write_cat_seq(sequences)
36 print('Saved and Complete')
```

NameError: name 'sequences' is not defined

my_file = "chr1_abc_def.fasta"

```
>lcl|NC_000021
ATGCGGCT...
>lcl|NC_000022
ATGCGGCt...
```

These functions should take my_file which contains alterheader lines for each coding region of DNA.

Read .fasta file of DNA coding regions while removing header and splicing them together.

```
# read fasta file of DNA coding regions while removing header and splicing them together.
def read_fasta(file_name):
    sequences = []
    seq = []
    with open(file_name) as fh:
        while True:
            if fh.readline().startswith(">"):
                fh.readline()
            else: 
                seq = fh.readline().rstrip()
                if len(seq) == 0:
                    break
        sequences.append(seq)
    return sequences
```

Save the appended sequence as a single length DNA .fasta

```
def write_cat_seq(sequences):
    output_seq = "chr21_coding_region_concat.fasta"
    print(output_seq)
    output = open(output_seq, 'w')
    output.write(sequences)
    output.close()
    print("File %s saved" % output_seq)
```

Run functions

```
file_name = "chr21_dna_sequence.fasta"
read_fasta(file_name)
write_cat_seq(file_name, sequences)
print('Saved and Complete')
```

Comment: I looked over the return it is correct in the code but was not on the question, just corrected it.

Comment: `return sequences` doesn't mean that the caller now has the `sequences` variable. You need to explicitly save the return value.

Comment: That last "run functions" thing... isn't that your problem? It doesn't define `sequences` but tries to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you forgot to store the result of `read_fasta(file_name)` in a `sequences` list, so it is not defined.

Here is a correct version of your code:

```
file_name = "chr21_dna_sequence.fasta"
sequences = read_fasta(file_name)
write_cat_seq(file_name, sequences)
print('Saved and Complete')
```